# displaying a part of text in view in laravel

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I am making a page where posts are shown [by title and **a part of body**].
in my view page I am using `{{$post->body}}` which shows the whole body of a post. 
And i cant think of any anything(helper,method) that gets some words at the beginning of body

Answer (score 0):

try like below ...

```
{!! str_limit($post->body , 100) !!}
```

it will display 100 lenth of your text(you can also pass whatever number you wish instead of 100).

Comment: my problem solved. [According to some rules in the website, it is not good to say thanks to you guys @DejavuGuy ]

Comment: Latest laravel version requires using this method instead of the above ```{!! Str::limit($post->body , 20) !!} ```

Answer (score 0):

u can use `substr()` method of php

examples:

```
<?php
    $stringName="Hello world";
    echo substr($stringName,6);//output= world
    echo substr($stringName,0,5);//output= Hello
    echo substr($stringName,1,6);//output= ello w
?>
```

in case of question

```
{{substr($post->body,0,15)."....."}}
```

Comment: my problem solved. [According to some rules in the website, it is not good to say thanks to you guys @Bhandari ]

Comment: you can always appreciate others help by up voting their answers if their answers fulfill your requirement.